# Mongo has many relation generating wrong mongoid query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a relation between customer and purchase one to many. Where my customer class is :

```
class Customer
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :purchases
end
```

Here is my purchase class :

```
class Purchase
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :customer, class_name: "Customer", foreign_key: :customer_id
end
```

I think I have keys setuped correctly. Not sure if it's wortwhile noting that both Customer and Purchase get populated by external process that seeds the mongodb.

But here is the part about wrongly generated queries, example 1 (from rails console):

```
Customer.first.purchases
```

Generates this query :

```
{"find"=>"purchases", "filter"=>{"customer_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('59a48bc9be66bdb7de3108b5')}}
```

But the right query is :

```
{"find"=>"purchases", "filter"=>{"customer_id"=>1006}}
```

Same thing when I approach this from the other side of the relation :

```
Purchase.first.customer
```

Generates this :

```
{"find"=>"customers", "filter"=>{"_id"=>10006}, "sort"=>{"_id"=>1}, "limit"=>1, "singleBatch"=>true}
```

But the right query would be :

```
{"find"=>"customers", "filter"=>{"customer_id"=>10006}, "sort"=>{"_id"=>1}, "limit"=>1, "singleBatch"=>true}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Question update:**

Also when I try to manually manipulate data, again trying rails console :

```
purchase = Purchase.last
purchase.customer_id = 10006
purhcase.save!
```

Yields this :

```
Mongoid::Errors::Validations: 
message:
  Validation of Purchase failed.
summary:
  The following errors were found: Customer can't be blank
resolution:
  Try persisting the document with valid data or remove the validations.
```

But I can actually go ahead and find this record :

```
Customer.where(customer_id: 10006).any?
D, [2017-08-28T18:04:32.053474 #86323] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:27017 | api_be_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"customers", "filter"=>{"customer_id"=>10006}}
D, [2017-08-28T18:04:32.054697 #86323] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:27017 | api_be_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.0009580000000000001s
=> true
```